# The above code will give me null in the field since my app uses password authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
void _addMessage(String value) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("interest_chat").add({
        'author': user.displayName ?? "Anonymous",
        'author_id': user.uid,
        'timestamp': Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        'value': value,
      });
    }
  }
```

The above code will give me null in the 'author' field since my app uses password authentication. But i want to display the username which is stored in another collection of firebase, it is in the location of `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.uid)`
I'm really new to flutter and firebase, this is my first app i am making for my school project, any help or guidance will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could've been framed better but based on my understanding, it seems new users do not have a `displayName` associated with the `user` object since you are using the email_id + password sign up option and you wish to retrieve the username which is stored in another collection of firestore under "users".

```
Future<String> _getUsername() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final docSnap =
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.uid).get();
  return docSnap.get(
      'userName'); //assuming the field within the document is titled ‘userName’
}

void _addMessage(String value) async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    final userName = await _getUsername();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("interest_chat").add({
      'author': userName,
      'author_id': user.uid,
      'timestamp': Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'value': value,
    });
  }
}
```